# Sequence of uniformly bounded linear opeartors

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a sequence of bijective bounded linear operators $L_n:X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are hilbert spaces. Further, we have that there exists an $M$ such that $\sup_{n} \{\| L_n\| \} < M$ --so these are uniformly bounded.

The bijectivity between the two Hilbert spaces tells us that $L_n^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ exists and is a bounded linear operator for each $n$. So for each $n$ there exists some $K_n$ such that $\|L_n^{-1}\| < K_n$. I want to show that there exists a $K$ such that $\sup_{n} \{\| L_n^{-1}\| \} < K$; that is, the sequence of inverse operators is uniformly bounded.

Is this enough to get a uniform bound on the the sequence $L_n^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.  Consider the case $L_n = I/n$.

Comment: Excellent counter-example. I had something similar in mind.

Comment: Nice, very clean. Thanks!